# Avoid cartesian join with "INNER JOIN TABLE(user_defined_array)"?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, user-defined-types

I know how to avoid cartesian joins with an inner join in general cases.

Is there a way to avoid a cartesian join, in Oracle, when joining to a table created from a user-defined array, like so?

```
select col1, col2, ...
from mytable mt
inner join TABLE(user_defined_number_array(1,2,3,4)) t ON t.column_value = mytable.col1
... --inner join other tables
...
where mt.col1 IN (
  SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(user_defined_number_array(1,2,3,4))
);
```

(In this case, `user_defined_number_array` is a table of number(18), and col1 is of the same type.)

Is the only way around this to define a table type with a keyed value? (Note that, for the purposes of this, I expect the arrays to be quite small - probably never more than ten rows.)

Thank you.

EDIT: Explain plan is below, and I've updated the query to better reflect what I'm doing. I didn't obscure the explain plan, because I figure it probably isn't worth it.

```
Plan hash value: 3336195920

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                    | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                             |                     |    18 |  1224 |   183K  (1)| 00:36:40 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER                          |                     |    18 |  1224 |   183K  (1)| 00:36:40 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                               |                     |    18 |  1026 |   183K  (1)| 00:36:40 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                              |                     |    18 |   792 |   183K  (1)| 00:36:40 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                             |                     |    18 |   684 |   183K  (1)| 00:36:40 |
|   5 |      MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                    |                     |  8168 | 32672 |   179K  (1)| 00:36:00 |
|   6 |       COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH  |                     |       |       |            |          |
|   7 |       BUFFER SORT                            |                     |  8168 | 16336 |            |          |
|   8 |        SORT UNIQUE                           |                     |       |       |            |          |
|   9 |         COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|                     |       |       |            |          |
|  10 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID             | LOG_ACTIVITY        |     1 |    34 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                       | LOG_ACTIVITYC3      |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID              | RESPONSE_CODE       |     1 |     6 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                       | RESPONSE_CODEP1     |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID               | LOG_ACTIVITY_TYPE   |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                        | LOG_ACTIVITY_TYPEP1 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                | EMPLOYEE            |     1 |    11 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                         | EMPLOYEEP1          |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you really sure that cartesian join is really wrong in your case? In order to avoid this, you can use either `CARDINALITY` hint or higher level for dynamic sampling to tell Oracle how many rows to expect from `TABLE` cast.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux The cartesian join occurs in the inner join clause. Note that this is not the full query - I also haven't included the explain plan. (I'm hesitant to do so as I'm working on a company project. I may be able to obscure it, though.)

Comment: @ibre5041 I'm not sure. That's why I'm asking. :P To be honest - I was under the impression that a cartesian join was always wrong unless you were specifically doing a `CROSS JOIN`; either you've missed a join condition by accident, or you are trying to cross join two disparate tables. I could be wrong, though! Seeking knowledge on this subject.

Comment: What if you put the "array table" into a CTE and join to that? `with defined_numbers as (select * from user_defined_number_array(1,2,3,4)) select ... from mytable join defined_numbers t on ...`?

Comment: For Oracle cross join is the the "fastest" way how to join two empty(or nearly empty) tables. So if you check exec plan for the query and you see very low number of expected rows for one of the tables, then you have an explanation. Your case is special because there are no stats for table `t`. But in this case dynamic sampling should "analyze" that table 1st and then CBO should generate the plan. Try to use `use_nl` or `use_hash` hints to force other joining strategy.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung Yes, I thought about that just after having posted my comment: to build the inner join result set, Oracle _might_ have to walk along the cross product and compare each row pairs. But you should try to build a simple and reproducible example -- respecting more or less the _cardinality_ of your tables. At the very least, in order to examine the query execution plan. The Oracle choice here is not necessary as bad as you think.

Comment: Is there an index on `mytable.col1`? If not then Oracle probably decides between hash join and cross join. If both tables are very small then cross join might be the fastest way how to evaluate the query.

Comment: The tables are fairly small....now (MyTable is ~150,000 rows.). In production, we expect these to be large. There is an index on col1 in this case. I suppose that, once the tables become large enough, the oracle statistics will begin mandating a hash join instead of a cartesian join? My fear is that, in production, this set of queries will begin performing badly as the tables grow.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Perhaps that's worth a shot. If anything, it should reduce code duplication, as this is part of a stored procedure (and that array gets used twice for each refcursor).

Comment: 150K rows is not many but is now a few. Post exec. plan and check how many rows Oracle expects to see.

Comment: Maybe you have another problem, the inner join and the where condition have the same meaning. I think you can get rid on of them and result will be the same.

Comment: @ibre5041 The result is the same, but the cardinality and execution plan aren't. Without the where clause, there's no cartesian join, but the cardinality increases to 144K rows for all of the joins instead of the 18 in the current plan. It looks as though Oracle's doing some type of optimization with the where clause, restricting the nested loops to a subset of the rows instead of the entire table. I added the where clause to avoid that, but got a cartesian join instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80795/discussion-between-ibre5041-and-jedd-ahyoung).

Comment: I looks like the value 8168 is the default value to the `TABLE` cast cardinality. Try to remove the where condition and add hint `/*+ CARDINALITY(t, 10) */`